# how to compare selected items from two lists simultaneosly..and cary operation on it?

Tags: android, android-layout, exception

i m beinner to android....i hav two listviews i want to select one item from each list and cary poeration on the selected items from these two listviews...i tried listview.setonselecteditemlistener but it gives error each time i m tring to load it....

```
here is program........



package com.a2zunitconverter.miniproject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class lenght extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lenght);  
    double var1;
    double var2;
        final EditText query=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.lquery);
        final EditText result=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.lresult);
    var1=Double.parseDouble(query.getText().toString());
    final ListView listfrom=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listfrom);
    final ListView listto=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listto);
   String[] quantity={"Meter","Inches","Feet","Yard"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,quantity);
    listfrom.setAdapter(adapter);
    listto.setAdapter(adapter);
    listfrom.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (listfrom.getSelectedItem()=="Meter" && listto.getSelectedItem()=="Inches");{
                result.setText("" + query);
            }
        }
    });
}

}
```

Comment: can you please post log trace? when the error occurs at loading list values or when clicking item list value?

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-03 08:48:35.292: E/AndroidRuntime(376): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.a2zunitconverter.miniproject/com.a2zunitconverter.miniproject.Area}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
07-03 08:48:35.292: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1405)
07-03 08:48:35.292: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1ndroid.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)

Comment: check the answer in your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304243/how-to-open-more-than-one-xml-forms-from-a-single-main-page/11304543#11304543 .. have to declare all the activity in manifest file.

Comment: what to chek in manifest reguardng ths question????/

Comment: according to your log trace it says that you are not declaring activity   com.a2zunitconverter.miniproject.Area in manifest.. so check whether you have declare all the activity in manifest and whether you calling area activity in this class??

Comment: i jst added it to manifest...and m nt calng area activity n ths operation

Comment: Thn check the logcat whether some other exception was thrown? since according to your exception activity not declared in manifest..